# Extjs DataView not refreshing - always getting emptyText value

Tags: extjs

I have a backend, which returns a JSON, I load that into a store, it loads fine, then call a refresh on the view from the controller, and I always get the emptyText value of the view, template is not refeshing.

EDIT: It is working now! The below setup if functioning, the problem was how I used to lookup the view.

Controller:

```
showNotes: function(activityId) {
    var me = this;
    Ext.Ajax.request({

        url: MyApp.Config.BASE_URL + '/someURL',
        method: 'GET',
        success: me.successGetNotes.bind(me),
        failure: me.failureGetNotes
    });
},

successGetNotes: function(result) {
        var notesStore = this.getNotesStore(),  //This gets me the store ok
            publishersStore = this.getPublishersStore(),
            data = Ext.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
        notesStore.loadRawData(data.result.notes);
        publishersStore.loadRawData(data.result.publishers);
        this.getNotesPanel().refresh();   //this calls the refresh on the DataView ok
        //TODO
    },
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Note', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'publisherId',
        'text' ,
        {
            name: 'created',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'c' 
        }
    ]
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Notes', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Note',
    alias: 'store.Notes',
    storeId: 'Notes'
});
```

main view:

```
...
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'notes-panel',
            //store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Notes'), NO!!!
            store: 'Notes',  //YES!
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
...
```

notes-panel:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.sections.notes.NotesPanel' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    alias: 'widget.notes-panel',
    //deferInitialRefresh: false,

    itemSelector: 'div.something',
tpl:  new Ext.XTemplate(

   //  '<tpl for=".">',
   //  '<div class="something">',
   //      '<p>ID:{publisherId}</p>',
   //      '<p>{text}</p>',
   //      '<p>{created}</p>',
   // '</div>'
   // '</tpl>',

   '<table width="100%" border="0">',
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class = "something">',
        '<tr><td width="85">ID:</td><td width="315">{publisherId}</td></tr>',
        '<tr><td>Note:</td><td>{text}</td></tr>',
        '</div>',
   '</tpl>',
   '<table>'
),

    emptyText: 'No data available'

})
;
```

Example response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "publishers": [
            {
              "id": "009999",
              "type": "xy",
              "isReceipient": false,
              "description": "xy"
            },
            {
              "id": 45,
              "type": "xy",
              "isReceipient": true,
              "description": "xy"
            },
            {
              "id": 45,
              "type": "xy",
              "isReceipient": false,
              "description": ""
            }
            ],
            "notes": [
            {
              "publisherId": "009999",
              "text": "xy",
              "created": "2014-02-23T18:24:06.074Z"
            },
            {
              "publisherId": "45",
              "text": "xy",
              "created": "2014-02-23T18:24:06.074Z"
            },
            {
              "publisherId": 45,
              "text": "xy",
              "created": "2014-02-23T18:24:06.074Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And another thing: I would also like to use publisherId in notes to print the publisher name and type, so I will need two store's data. I was thinking of loading the other store by lookup in the DataView, and getting the publisher that way. Is that feasible?

Comment: Your calling publishers when you want notes I think.

Comment: I call both actually. I will also need publishers, but I don't do anything with the publisher store yet. I don't see any wrong call :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [`Ext.DataView.itemSelector`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-itemSelector):

> A simple CSS selector (e.g. div.some-class or span:first-child) that will be used to determine what nodes this DataView will be working with. The itemSelector is used to map DOM nodes to records. As such, there should only be **one root level element that matches the selector for each record**.

and like you can the in the example from DataView:

```
var imageTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="thumb-wrap">',
          '<img src="{src}" />',
          '<br/><span>{caption}</span>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

the class is under the `tpl` element, so I think in your example you need to create a `div` under the `tpl` node.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help :( I moved the div inside the node, I also re-wrote it like in the example, and still does not work.

Comment: ok can you update your post accordingly? and test a few things:
1. is `notesStore.getCount()` > 0 ? 
2. remove `this.getNotesPanel().refresh()` cause it should refresh automatically if the data is changed
3. is `this.getNotesPanel().getCount()` > 0 ?

Comment: Updated the post. notesStore.getCount is 3 ( I have the JSON as response as in the post). the refresh is undifened on the View class. this.getNotesPanel yields: constructor {xtype: "notes-panel", store: constructor, flex: 1, initialConfig: Object, events: Object…}
In the store property, the data do have an empty array though, whether I refresh view or not. But if I take out the refresh, I don't even get the emtyText. Guess it's because somehow the view does not get notified by the change of the store, but I can't see why.

Comment: Ah, it is working!!! Finally. Strange, the problem was I used lookup to find the store for the view. Now I just use it's ID. I will update the post, the problme was in the main view: store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Notes'), Did not work, now I use: store: 'Notes', and works. The lookup was copied from the controller actually, I debugged it there, it worked fine. Thank you for your help, your debug suggestion led me to find the problem!

Comment: Ah yes,  every store definition in extjs is only a string, should have seen this :D